# can I use was in the sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction

Is the following sentence correct?

> In recent days, life was very hard for me.

Note that  In this case I want to mean that my life was hard a day or a few days ago but the hard time has now gone.

Comment: "was" is good, yes, but it clashes with "recent days". How about using "last week" or something to show that you mean the past.

Comment: "Recent" signifies from a point in the past until the present moment. So, as Mr Lister suggests, you either need to define the period concerned or use the present perfect *has been*.

Answer (score 1):

Here you should go for present perfect continuous if you intend to convey that life is still hard for you..

> In recent days, life has been very hard for me.

Instead if you wish to mean that the hard part was a few days ago..

> Until recent days, life was very tough for me.

Comment: "recent days" isn't idiomatic. "recently" and "until recently" might be better.

Comment: Yes I completely agree. I had thought of writing the same, but I didn't want to change his original sentence completely. That's why I framed it as above. Thanks for the suggestion though ! :)